# I can't send gps values via the eclipse emulator control panel

Tags: android, gps, android-emulator

I try to send gps longitude and latitude to the android emulator with eclipse, but the values seem to never be set. Instead the onStatusChanged method of my listener is called. **Edit** I send those values through the emulator controls in the ddms view in eclipse.

If I send data via telnet I get the correct data shown and the onLocationChanged method of my listener is changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bug with location controls of ADT in Eclipse if you're using a locale other than English. To fix it, you have to add **"-Duser.language=en"** (*without the quotation
marks*) on a separate line to your **eclipse.ini** file. You can take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=915) issue for details.

Comment: This is still valid in Helios SP2 as of May 10th 2011…

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you got your permissions set

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  
android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION
```

Comment: Glad it helped, took me a while to get this one too.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem but it solved now just because my emulator not using google API mode

adt bundle from developer.android running smoothly